# How to get a specific python's config information

Tags: python

I remember there is a command can show under which option a specific python was build, but I forget it QAQ

the option I mean is like this:

when compile python from source, we use:

`./configure --prefix=/a/path/ --cflags=something`

Answer (score 1):

`python -c "import sysconfig; print sysconfig.get_config_var('CONFIG_ARGS')"`

This is the answer~